# To describe the action

Tags: expressions

I try to say we don't keep living but people yesterday like us died and we are new born today. I mean this totally literally:

No Let's hypothesize that the smallest time unit is 1 minute.

There are 2 minutes. In the first minute, there is light on the left, and in the second minute, there is light on the right. Many people describe them as 'light moves to the right' but can I describe them as 'light in the 1st minute is turned off in the 2nd minute, and new light in the 2nd minute is turned on (or new made)'?

Comment: I don't understand the picture.  I see two yellow stripes towards the left of the screen. One is marked A the other is B.  I don't see any relation to the the question about "scene 2" or "lights moving foward".  Try to ask about what your real question is.  What are these lights?  If they aren't real but just an example, then what is "real".

Comment: I symbolized light as the yellow things.

Comment: What is the actual context.  Nobody ever describes things like this.  What do you really want to say?

Comment: I try to say we don't keep living but people yesterday like us died and we are new born today.

Comment: Okay,  so now we are getting somewhere.  The question is nothing about "lights" It is about lives.  Now are you being literal or metaphorical?  Remember, I can't advise on the correctness of the philosophy.

Comment: It's totally literal. I just want to advise on expressing this correctly.

Comment: You could say, "There are two lights. When the one on the left goes off, the one on the right comes on." But I don't know what the smallest time units have to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(answering the question in the comments)

You can say "I believe that the person I was yesterday died when I fell asleep, and a new person was born today when I woke up.

It grammatically correct. Philosophically it is problematic (If you are a new person, why should you inherit the old person's money, or job, or spouse)

In the physical case of lights.  It is possible to have one light that you move. It is possible to have two lights.  But these are different.

> I turned off light A and a little later turned on light B.

has a different meaning to

> I turned off a light in position A, moved it to position B and turned it back on.

In the first example, there are two lights. In the second there is only one.